# Minimizing Animation JavaFX Undecorated Stage

Tags: java, javafx, jna

I attempting to recreate my own control bar in a javafx application, so I set the window as UNDECORATED to be able to implement my own button, but with the removal of the original control bar comes the deletion of any window animation such as the ones you got from minimazing the window or maximasing it. I use jna to correctly reimplant the reduce behaviors but there is still no animation.

I tried to change the newStyle value by other one from https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-styles but if the animation goes back it also means the the original control bar come back.

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/test.fxml"));
    root.setId("pane");
    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle("test");
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    long lhwnd = com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).getNativeWindow();
    Pointer lpVoid = new Pointer(lhwnd);
    HWND hwnd = new HWND(lpVoid);
    final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
    int oldStyle = user32.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000;//WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
```

Comment: You might consider covering the undesired control bar with your own, or cover the window that _will_ animate with one that will not (slaving the animating window to the non-animating one.  Reaching too far into the actual native implementations results in unmaintainable code.

Comment: That's a good idea but that's not really suitable in every cases, i'm effraid that it would complicate my windows gestion whereas there is only one technical parameter to make that work, i'm sure there is a way to isolate the controlbar while saying that the window is undecorated, or to reactivate the animations right after

Comment: See https://github.com/kalibetre/CustomDecoratedJFrame
It fixed the problem for Swing (JFrame) and also for [Compose Multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform). May be applied to JavaFX too.